# Asymptotic behaviour of the specific series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $a$ be real number. There is a sequence.
$$b_{n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos(\ln (k))}{k^{a}}$$

> Find asymptotic behaviour of $b_{n}$. It is find function $f$ so that $b_{n}=O(f(n))$

First of all i know that $b_{n}$ tends to $0$. Apart of it i can't tell anything special.

I hope you will give me some hints.

Regards.

Comment: @YuriyS. Thanks for "clarifying" for me. There too many times where I am just unable to "see" some things (this is just a way of talking !).

Comment: If $a > 1$, then $b_n = O(\frac{1}{n^{a-1}})$.

Comment: For better estimates, do summation by parts...

Comment: If $a \le 0$, the series diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a complex sequence ($i$ is the imaginary unit):

$$c_{n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k k^i}{k^{a}}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^{a-i}}$$

Then $b_n=\Re (c_n)$.

Using the definition of [Hurwitz zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html), we have:

$$c_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{a-i}} \left(\zeta \left(a-i, \frac{n+1}{2} \right)-\zeta \left(a-i, \frac{n+2}{2} \right) \right)$$

From the integral definition for this function (for $a>0$):

$$\zeta \left(a-i, \frac{n+1}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a-i)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{- \frac{n+1}{2} t} t^{a-1-i} dt}{1-e^{-t}}$$

So we have:

$$c_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{a-i} \Gamma(a-i)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{- \frac{n+1}{2} t} (1-e^{-\frac12 t}) t^{a-1-i} dt}{1-e^{-t}} =\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{a-i} \Gamma(a-i)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{- \frac{n}{2} t} t^{a-1-i} dt}{1+e^{\frac12t}}$$

When $n \to \infty$ only small $t$ contribute to the integral, so let's make a change of variable and then we can do some series expansion:

$$t=\frac{2}{n} u$$

> $$c_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{a-i}\Gamma(a-i)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{- u} u^{a-1-i} du}{1+e^{u/n}}$$
>
> This expression is exact, and taking the real part, we can also obtain an exact integral expression for $b_n$.

Asymptotic series for $n \to \infty$ can be obtained in a variety of ways. If $a>1$ then the integral converges absolutely, no matter what we do with the denominator.

Obviously, we can expand:

$$1+e^{u/n}=2 + \frac{u}{n}+ \frac{u^2}{2n^2} + O(u^3/n^3)$$

Taking the first term only, we obtain:

> $$c_n \asymp \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n^{a-i}}, \qquad n \to \infty$$

Taking the real part here is easy enough. For more terms we'll have to consider more complicated integrals.

Of course, it might be better to work with the original $t$ integral and use [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) to obtain explicit asymptotic series.

Comment: But what if $a\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @mkultra, then this method probably needs to be modified

Comment: Because given functions are asymptotically equal and both are smooth i think that $c_{n}=\theta(\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{2n^{(a-i)}})$ even for $a\in(0,1)$

Comment: Then why it is said in this definition that $a$ must be grater than $1$?

Comment: @mkultra, that condition was wrong.When $0<a<1$, the integral still converges, because for $u \to 0$ we have an integrable singularity. I'll edit the post